# Merge Two or more list according to order

Tags: c#

I have two Lists

```
List<string> Name = new List<string>();
List<string> Address = new List<string>();
```

Both the lists having 30 data. I want to merge both the lists to get a complete Information lists like

```
List<string, string> CompleteInformation = new List<string, string>();
```

Also if I want to merge more than two list in one how it can be done.

Comment: Do you mean a Dictionary<string, string> ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for `Zip` method:

```
var CompleteInformation = Name.Zip(Address, (n, a) => new { Address = a, Name = n }).ToList();
```

Gives you list of anonymous type instances, with two properties: `Address` i `Name`.

**Update**

You can call `Zip` more then once:

```
var CompleteInformation
    = Name.Zip(Address, (n, a) => new { Address = a, Name = n })
          .Zip(AnotherList, (x, s) => new { x.Address, x.Name, Another = s })
          .ToList();
```

Comment: Oh, this is incredible!  No need for creating a separate container.  I'm going to be using this all the time.

Comment: Thank you MarcinJuraszek. But if I have more than two lists then what should I do. For instance let us assume if i have two more lists named

List<string> City = new List<string>();
List<string> State = new List<string>();

and i want to combine these in the same completeInformation lists

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek : thank you very very much Marcin. This is what i wanted. You great man. Once again thank you.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek : i want to have this code in a loop and i want to instantiate this CompleteInformation outside the loop so that I can return it a from a method. 

I'm trying this : 

List<string> CompleteInformation = new List<string>();

But its not working.

Comment: @Pranab anonymous types are not good to pass around as method results. You'd have to create your own type you'd like to return from method and construct that type instances as result of `Zip` calls.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to store the information, and [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to take the info from both lists, like this

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> bothLists = Name.Zip(Address, (n, a) => new Tuple<string, string>(n, a)).ToList();
```

But the best way in my opinion would be to create a class related to your domain :

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

And then

```
List<Person> bothLists = Name.Zip(Address, (n, a) => new Person{Address = a, Name = n}).ToList();
```

---

However, if you have multiple lists you need to nest multiple Zips, and that's not pretty. If you are *sure* all lists have the same number of elements, just iterate over them.

In LINQ :

```
List<Person> multipleLists = Name.Select((t, i) => new Person
    {
        Name = t, Address = Address[i], ZipCode = ZipCode[i]
    }).ToList();
```

Without LINQ (seriously, there's nothing wrong with a for loop)

```
List<Person> multipleLists = new List<Person>();
for (int i = 0; i < Name.Count; i++)
{
    multipleLists.Add(new Person
        {
            Name = Name[i],
            Address = Address[i],
            ZipCode = ZipCode[i]
        });
}
```

You can also use a `Tuple<string, string, string, [...]>` if you want to stay away from classes.

Comment: I'm sorry for the chatty comment, but I just have to say it -- your name is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a dictionary method of something like this:

```
var people = Name.Zip(Address, (n, a) => new { n, a })
             .ToDictionary(x => x.n, x => x.a);
```

You can then access the keys and values.  Easy to search for information.