# How to use linq to assign two lists and an int to create one list of a new object?

Tags: c#, linq

I have:

```
List<int> keys; //These lists are the same size
List<int> reportKeys; //These lists are the same size
int reportType;
```

I want to create a new List of MyType:

```
List<MyType>

public class MyType
{
    public int Key {get;set;}
    public int ReportKey {get;set;}
    public int ReportType {get;set;}
}
```

I could use a for loop to assign these:

```
var objects = new List<MyObject>();
for (var i = 0; i < keys.Count(); i++)
{
    objects.Add(new MyObject { Key = keys[i], ReportKey = reportKeys[i], ReportType = reportType };
}
```

Is there a way to do this with linq and not use a for loop?

Comment: Or see [Merge Two or more list according to order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21951459/merge-two-or-more-list-according-to-order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ `Zip` ([refer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Sample below:

```
var result = keys.Zip(reportsKey, 
                     (key, reportKey) => new MyObject 
                                                { 
                                                    Key = key, 
                                                    ReportKey = reportKey, 
                                                    ReportType = reportType 
                                                 })
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry, accidentialy cut it. Already pasted.

Answer (score 7):

Try using Linq's [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method:

```
var objects = keys.Zip(reportKeys, (key, reportKey) => new MyType
    {
        Key = key,
        ReportKey = reportKey,
        ReportType = reportType
    }).ToList();
```